# SQL Server : fastest way to change rows to columns

Tags: sql, join, sql-server-2012, pivot, exists

I've got an issue regarding two tables in my database that have the following columns:

`COMMENT` table

```
KEY 
TYPE
NUMBER
TEXT
```

Composite key made up of `(KEY, TYPE, NUMBER)`

`RESULTS` table

```
KEY
TYPE1
TYPE2
...
TYPE20
TEXT1
TEXT2
...
TEXT20
```

An example of the `COMMENT` table would be this:

```
KEY | TYPE | NUMBER | TEXT|
1      A     0001     SAMPLETEXT
1      A     0002     SAMPLETEXT2
1      B     0001     SAMPLETEXT3
1      B     0002     SAMPLETEXT4
1      B     0003     SAMPLETEXT5
2      C     0001     SAMPLETEXT6
2      C     0002     SAMPLETEXT7
3      A     0001     SAMPLETEXT8
```

For each `KEY`, there are only 3 different types `A,B,C` and one `TYPE` may have up to 0020 in the `NUMBER` field. These records are ordered by **KEY** then by **TYPE**

I need to accomplish the following: for each `KEY` in `COMMENT` table, insert the first **20** `TYPE` rows into each column inside de `RESULTS` table (`TYPE1` for the first type in the Comment table, `TYPE2` for the second type in the comment table and so on) and insert the first 20 TEXT rows into each column inside the RESULTS table (`TEXT1` for the first text, `TEXT2` for the second text and so on)

The `RESULTS` table would look like this:

```
KEY | TYPE1 | TYPE2 | TYPE3 | ... | TYPE20 | TEXT1 | TEXT2 | ... | TEXT20
1      A        A      B             NULL    SAMPTE1 SAMPTE2       NULL
2      C        C      NULL          NULL    SAMPTE6 SAMPTE7       NULL
3      A     NULL      NULL  ...    NULL     SAMPTE7 NULL    ....  NULL
```

The `RESULTS` table would have a row per each **KEY** and up to 20 **TEXT** fields along with their corresponding type.

As you can see, this `RESULTS` table was clearly bad designed. It was made in the 70's and we can't change it.

Some questions might pop up when implementing this, here are the answers:

1. What if a **KEY** has more than 20 **TEXT** in the `COMMENT` table? We don't care, we just insert the first 20 of them
2. What if I have 23 type A text and 10 type B text, for example? Then just the first 20 type A text would appear in `RESULTS`
3. Is there any way the `RESULTS` table could be changed? Unfortunately there isn't.
4. Does **TYPE1** match **TEXT1** in the `RESULTS` table and **TYPE2** match **TEXT2** and so on? Yes, also, the amount of columns that match is the same.
5. If there are less than 20 TEXT in `COMMENT` table, the rest of the values of **TEXT** and **TYPE** in RESULTS is null? Yes

The question is, what is the cleanest, fastest, scalable, non tedious way of implementing this?

Also, how could it be implemented, such that in a future the RESULTS table could have N more `TYPE` columns and N more `TEXT` columns?

I've heard about using PIVOT tables, joins and many other techniques but I don't know how to make this thing happen.

Comment: hi, perhaps you could [pivot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38369584/pivot-in-sql-server-2012-new-to-sql)

Comment: The one question you don't address is WHY you would want to do this in SQL. It's a clear SQL Anti-Pattern / Code Smell. If it's for presentation, doing this in the database is the wrong location, if it's for further SQL processing or storage, it's a poor structure; both SQL (the language) and RDBMSes are designed explicitly for the structure you started with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read all about [pivot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot) operations in the T-SQL documentation. Your answer requires a double pivot: once to pivot the `Type` for each `[Key,Number]` combination and once to pivot the `Text` for each `[Key,Number]` combination.

In order to avoid additional aggregations on the `Key` column, you can split these two pivot actions in separate subqueries. The solution below places those two pivot subqueries in two [common table expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql) (CTE's) named `piv1` and `piv2`. Note that each subquery starts from only those columns required for the output. This column filtering is done with an additional subquery called `comm`.

The final query [joins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/joins) `piv1` and `piv2` on their common `Key` column and [inserts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/insert-transact-sql) the output in the predefined `Result` table.

A non-tedious way for N `Type` or `Text` columns will require dynamic SQL. *While such a solution is non-tedious it is also very non-trivial!* If you are still new to concepts like `join` and `pivot` as your question suggests, then I strongly advise against going that route for now. Copy-pasting some column names will be much faster than developing and maintaining a dynamic SQL query.

**Sample data**

```
create table Comment
(
  [Key] int,
  [Type] nvarchar(1),
  [Number] nvarchar(4), --> changing to numeric type will drop the leading zeros
  [Text] nvarchar(20)
)

insert into Comment ([Key], [Type], [Number], [Text]) values
(1, 'A', '0001', 'SAMPLETEXT'),
(1, 'A', '0002', 'SAMPLETEXT2'),
(1, 'B', '0001', 'SAMPLETEXT3'),
(1, 'B', '0002', 'SAMPLETEXT4'),
(1, 'B', '0003', 'SAMPLETEXT5'),
(2, 'C', '0001', 'SAMPLETEXT6'),
(2, 'C', '0002', 'SAMPLETEXT7'),
(3, 'A', '0001', 'SAMPLETEXT8');

create table Result
(
  [Key] int,
  [Type1] nvarchar(1),
  [Type2] nvarchar(1),
  [Type3] nvarchar(1),
  -- repeat for [Type4] to [Type19]
  [Type20] nvarchar(1),
  [Text1] nvarchar(20),
  [Text2] nvarchar(20),
  [Text3] nvarchar(20),
  -- repeat for [Text4] to [Text19]
  [Text20] nvarchar(20)
);
```

**Solution**

Combining a double `pivot` in separate CTE's, a `join` and an `insert` operation in a single query statement.

```
with piv1 as
(
  select piv.[Key] as [Key],
         piv.[0001] as [Type1],
         piv.[0002] as [Type2],
         piv.[0003] as [Type3],
         -- repeat for [Type4] to [Type19]
         piv.[0020] as [Type20]
  from ( select c.[Key], c.[Type], c.[Number] from comment as c ) as comm
  pivot (min(comm.[Type]) for comm.[Number] in ([0001], [0002], [0003], [0020])) piv -- add values [0004] to [0019]
),
piv2 as
(
  select piv.[Key] as [Key],
         piv.[0001] as [Text1],
         piv.[0002] as [Text2],
         piv.[0003] as [Text3],
         -- repeat for [Text4] to [Text19]
         piv.[0020] as [Text20]
  from ( select c.[Key], c.[Text], c.[Number] from comment as c ) as comm
  pivot (min(comm.[Text]) for comm.[Number] in ([0001], [0002], [0003], [0020])) piv -- add values [0004] to [0019]
)
insert into Result ([Key],
                    [Type1], [Type2], [Type3], [Type20], -- add columns [Type4] to [Type19]
                    [Text1], [Text2], [Text3], [Text20]) -- add columns [Text4] to [Text19]
select piv1.[Key],
       piv1.[Type1], piv1.[Type2], piv1.[Type3], piv1.[Type20], -- add columns piv1.[Type4] to piv1.[Type19]
       piv2.[Text1], piv2.[Text2], piv2.[Text3], piv2.[Text20]  -- add columns piv2.[Text4] to piv2.[Text19]
from piv1
join piv2 on piv2.[Key] = piv1.[Key];
```

**Result**

```
Key  Type1  Type2  Type3  Type20  Text1        Text2        Text3        Text20
---  -----  -----  -----  ------  -----------  -----------  -----------  -----------
1    A      A      B      null    SAMPLETEXT   SAMPLETEXT2  SAMPLETEXT5  null
2    C      C      null   null    SAMPLETEXT6  SAMPLETEXT7  null         null
3    A      null   null   null    SAMPLETEXT8  null         null         null
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c02cb905109fdd51391d9b95876a687d) to see things in action.

Comment: This is by far the best answer I was looking for! Thank you so much